# Server 2012 share over vpn

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-server-2012

I have a VPN between two routers, on location one I have a bunch of servers and on the second location I have a backup system. Until now I had a Windows 2000 Server running at the first location and was able to connect to a network share on the server from the second location over the VPN connection.

Now I wanted to replace the old Server with a new machine running Server 2012. I had everything set up like before with the old server, but now I can't get access to the share on the 2012 Server. I also cannot ping the new server from the second location, but I can ping all other machines on the network.

On the first location I have access to the share on the new server and I can ping it too.

What do I need to do to get it to work?

I couldn't find anything helpful on the Microsoft site, and Google wasn't helpful either, any ideas?

**Edit**

The firewall on the server is deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like a firewall issue to me. Fiddle around with the Windows firewall settings and see if you can get any results. If you can't get it to work and you're in a secure environment try disabling the firewall on Server 2012 to see if that has any effect at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the firewall is deactivated, added this in the post, too.